# Auto fill textbox if empty

Tags: jquery

Here I have add and comparing value of textbox. `Textbox1` is comparing the values of `textbox2, textbox3, textbox4 and textbox5`. If the value is greater or lower than the value of textbox1 the other textbox clears. What I need to do is, for i.e

If `textbox1 = 10` and `textbox2 = 10` the other textbox should automatically get a zero value.

Any help please?

Here's my working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WS6zG/

```
$('#smbt').on('click',function(){
    var textBox1=$("input[id='txtbox1']").val();
    var textBox2=$("input[id='txtbox2']").val();
    var textBox3=$("input[id='txtbox3']").val();
    var textBox4=$("input[id='txtbox4']").val();
    var textBox5=$("input[id='txtbox5']").val();

if((+textBox2 + +textBox3 + +textBox4 + +textBox5) > textBox1){
    $('#txtbox2').val('');
    $('#txtbox3').val('');
    $('#txtbox4').val('');
    $('#txtbox5').val('');
  alert('value is greater than quantity');  
    return false;
}else if((+textBox2 + +textBox3 + +textBox4 + +textBox5) < textBox1){
    $('#txtbox2').val('');
    $('#txtbox3').val('');
    $('#txtbox4').val('');
    $('#txtbox5').val('');
  alert('value is lower than quantity');  
    return false;
    }
    else{
    }
});
```

Comment: your fiddle link is wrong...post it again with correct link

Comment: @RakeshKumar Sorry, I updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way

```
<input type="text" id="first"/>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

jquery

```
$("#first").change(function(){
$("input:not(#first)").each(function(){
if(parseInt($("#first").val())>parseInt($(this).val()))
   {
   $(this).val("");
   }
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/33/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `onClick`

```
$("input:not(#txtbox1)").each(function(){
    var valuet = parseInt($(this).val());
    alert(valuet);
    if(valuet > textBox1)
    {   
        $(this).val(0);

    }
    else if(valuet < textBox1){
        $(this).val(0);

    }else if(valuet == textBox1){
        $(this).removeClass("txtboxClass");
        $(".txtboxClass").val(0);
        return false;   
    }   
});
```

`txtboxClass` class should be applied to all other textboxes except textBox1.

This will help you discontinue the loop when you get number equal to textBox1 value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Means in your button click event @user3318208

Comment: I tried it but not work. Can you attach it in my fiddle?

Comment: Sure. check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WS6zG/3/) @user3318208 Hope that's what you want :)

Comment: That was the to my current code. What I need is when textbox1 is 10 and textbox2 is 10 the other textbox should automatically get zero value

Comment: Means textbox 3, 4 and 5 should be 0 if textbox 1 = textbox 2? @user3318208

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WS6zG/4/)? @user3318208 0 instead of blank values?

Comment: yan should be 0 if textbox1 is reach it equal.

Comment: @user3318208 check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/WS6zG/7/). It discontinues the loop when gets value equal to textBox1 :)

Comment: all the textbox I have in my code gets the value of zero

Comment: So which textbox should be 0? @user3318208 only which is equal to textbox1?